# ReadableByteChannel hangs on read(bytebuffer)

Tags: java, multithreading, connection, bytebuffer, socketchannel

Im working on Instant messenger using java 1.6. IM uses multithreading - main thread, receiving, and ping. For tcp/ip communication I used SocketChannel. And it seems there is a problem with receiving bigger packages from server. Server instead of one sends a couple of packages and thats where the problem begins. Every first 8 bytes is telling what is the type of package and how big it is. This is how I managed reading:

```
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try{
        Headbuffer.clear();
        bytes = readChannel.read(Headbuffer); //ReadableByteChannel
        Headbuffer.flip();
        if(bytes != -1){
            int head = Headbuffer.getInt();
            int size = Headbuffer.getInt();
            System.out.println("received pkg: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(head)+" with size "+ size+" bytes);
            switch(head){
            case incoming.Pkg1: ReadWelcome(); break;
            case incoming.Pkg2: ReadLoginFail();break;
            case incoming.Pkg3: ReadLoginOk();break;
            case incoming.Pkg4: ReadUserList();break;
            case incoming.Pkg5: ReadUserData();break;
            case incoming.Pkg6: ReadMessage();break;
            case incoming.Pkg7: ReadTypingNotify();break;
            case incoming.Pkg8: ReadListStatus();break;
            case incoming.Pkg9: ChangeStatus();break;
            }
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

And during the tests everything was fine until i logged on my account and import my buddylist. I send request to server for statuses and he send me back about 10 out of 80 contacts. So I came up with something like this:

```
public synchronized void readInStatus(ByteBuffer headBuffer){

    byteArray.add(headBuffer); //Store every buffer in ArrayList
    int buddies = MainController.controler.getContacts().getSize();
    while(buddies>0){

          readStuff();
          readDescription();
        --buddies; 
    }       
}
```

and each readStuff() and readDescription() are checking each parameter size with remaining bytes in the buffer:

```
 if(byteArray.get(current).remaining() >= 4){

      uin = byteArray.get(current).getInt();
      }else{
          byteArray.add(Receiver.receiver.read());
          current = current +1;
          uin = byteArray.get(current).getInt(); 
      }
```

and Receiver.receiver.read() is:

```
public ByteBuffer read(){
    try {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(40000);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        bytes = readChannel.read(bb);
        bb.flip();
        return bb;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

So application is lunched, logged and then sends contacts. Server send me back just a piece of my list. But in the method **readInStatus(ByteBuffer headBuffer)** I try to force the rest of the list. And now the fun part - after some time it gets to the **Receiver.receiver.read()** and on **bytes = readChannel.read(bb)** it just stops and I dont know why , no errors no nothing even after some time and Im out of the ideas. Im fighting with this whole week and i dont get anywhere near the solution. I will appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

---

Thanks for response. Yes, I'm using blocking SocketChannel, I tried non-blocking but it goes wild and out of control so I skipped the idea. About the bytes I expect - this is kind of weird, because its giving me size only once in head but its size of the first part not the whole package, other parts is not containing header bytes at all. I can't predict how much bytes it would be, the reason is - descriptions with 255 bytes capacity. This is exactly why I've created variable **buddies** in : `public synchronized void readInStatus(ByteBuffer headBuffer)`
wich is basically length of my buddy list and before reading each field I'm checking if there is enough bytes left if its not, I do **read()**. But last field before description is integer with the length of the incoming description. But its impossible to determine how long package is, until some processing is done. @robert do you think I should try again switching to non-blocking SocketChannel in that situation ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you are sending fewer bytes than you are trying to read.  You might have missed writing something, written things in the wrong order, misread a size field or something like that.

I think I'd attack this problem by adding tracing code to count and log the number of bytes read and written, notional packect sizes and so on.  Then run, and compare the traces to see where things start to get out of sync.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. However I think I'm doing it right and everything is in place as it suppose to be. I've checked the size of the buffer before sending and its correct. Sending requires only two variables int and byte so its pretty easy math. Contacts are stored in Hashtable and I'm iterating from top to bottom.

Comment: The problem is the limit of the receiving buffer. You clear it, when you should set it to the 'size' size, read, clear then set the buffer limit based on the size, then read again in the same way for the data. I'm a network engineer BTW.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a blocking SocketChannel, then read will block until the buffer is filled or the server delivers end of stream. For a server with connection keep-alive, the server does not send end of stream - it will simply stop sending data, and the read will hang indefinitely or until timeout.

You could either:
(i) try using a non-blocking SocketChannel, repeatedly reading until the read delivers 0 bytes (but beware 0 bytes does not necessarily mean end of stream - it could mean an interruption) or
(ii) if you have to use the blocking version, and you know how many bytes you were expecting from the server e.g. from a header, when the number of bytes left to read is less than buffer.capacity(), move position and/or limit on the buffer so as to leave only the required space in the buffer before the read. I am working this solution now. If it works for you, please let me know!

So far as I can work out, if you have to use a blocking SocketChannel and you do not know how many bytes you are expecting, and the server does not send end of stream, there is no solution.

Comment: Can't get method (ii) to work at the moment. Still blocks even when I have moved position such that the available bytes to be read does not exceed buffer.remaining()